# Is there a way to make an apkmirror.com app behave exactly the same as the app from Google Play Store and Galaxy Store?

Tags: applications, google-play-store

There can be a subtle difference on how the app behave:

1. Xiaomi phones using Dual app for Pokemon Go
2. Galaxy phone using Pokemon Go from Google Play Store and Pokemon Go from Galaxy Store
3. OnePlus using Pokemon Go from Google Play Store and Pokemon Go from apkmirror.com (there is no other choice because it doesn't have a OnePlus Store)
4. Xiaomi phones using method (3) above just to experiment

I noticed if it is (3) and (4) above, then if we click on the Pokemon Go Store, the page is all blank.  If I show the app from apkmirror.com on the OnePlus App info -> Advanced in Settings, then it shows "None", as opposed to "Google Play Store".

Is there a way to make the app behave exactly the same as if it comes from the Google Play Store or Galaxy Store?

Comment: First there may be different app versions for each store. Where apkmirror.com gets it's versions is not defined, as users upload the APKs. Additionally Android records if an app has been installed from Google Play Store or not (using the "Play Store Install Referrer"). Based on this data an app can behave differently. Therefore it could be a different app and it could be the way how you have installed the app.

Comment: so theoretically, for Angry Birds Classic, when this app is removed from the Google Play Store, but archived on apkmirror.com, the app can really choose to think, "Not from Google Play Store and Not from Galaxy Store, therefore stop the app right there (not allowed to play)."

Comment: I just reread info about Play Store Install Referrer, it seems like this is Play Store only, therefore I don't know if Galaxy store also provides something like this. Using that referrer you could limit an app to direct Play Store installations. But I am not aware if any app really does something like this. Typically the installation referrer is mainly used for marketing.

Comment: ... and for automatic updates via google play